# how to change numeric into time format on y-axiss in RADCHART using asp.net

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have an issue related to `RadChart`. Here I want to take name on x-axis and time on y-axis so my `DataTable` having data with time format while binding those columns to `RadChart`. I am getting this error:

> The type of column with name  TargetedResponseTime is not numeric

How can I change the radchart settings into time formate

C#:

```
chartBronze.DataSource = dt_Bronze;  
chartBronze.PlotArea.XAxis.DataLabelsColumn = "TicketPriority";
chartBronze.Series[0].DataYColumn = "TargetedResponseTime";
chartBronze.Series[1].DataYColumn = "AverageResponseTime";
chartBronze.DataBind();
```

ASPX:

```
<telerik:RadChart ID="chartBronze"  runat="server" onitemdatabound="chartBronze_ItemDataBound" >
    <Appearance Corners="Round, Round, Round, Round, 7">
        <FillStyle MainColor="226, 247, 255">
        </FillStyle>
        <Border Color="82, 160, 226" />
    </Appearance>
    <PlotArea>
        <Appearance Dimensions-Width="70%" Dimensions-AutoSize="False" Dimensions-Height="60%"
            Dimensions-Margins="30%, 24%, 12%, 20%">
            <FillStyle FillType="Solid" MainColor="White">
            </FillStyle>
            <Border Color="180, 210, 236" />
        </Appearance>
        <XAxis>
            <Appearance Color="Black" MajorTick-Color="Brown" >
                <LabelAppearance Position-AlignedPosition="TopLeft">
                </LabelAppearance>
                <MajorGridLines Visible="false" />
                <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
                <TextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Black" TextProperties-Font="callabri">
                </TextAppearance>
            </Appearance>
        </XAxis>
        <YAxis AutoScale="false" MaxValue="60" MinValue="00" LabelStep="12">
            <Appearance Color="Black" MajorTick-Color="Brown" >                                     
                <MajorGridLines Color="Black"/>
                <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
                <TextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Black" TextProperties-Font="callabri">
                </TextAppearance>
            </Appearance>
        </YAxis>
    </PlotArea>
    <ChartTitle>
        <Appearance Position-AlignedPosition="Top">
            <FillStyle MainColor="226, 247, 255" SecondColor="226, 247, 255">
            </FillStyle>
        </Appearance>
        <TextBlock Text="SLA Bronze">
            <Appearance TextProperties-Color="Chocolate" TextProperties-Font="Calibri, 15pt">
                <FillStyle MainColor="226, 247, 255" SecondColor="226, 247, 255">
                </FillStyle>
            </Appearance>
        </TextBlock>
    </ChartTitle>
    <Legend>
        <Appearance Position-AlignedPosition="TopRight">
            <ItemTextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Black">
            </ItemTextAppearance>
            <ItemMarkerAppearance Figure="Rectangle">
            </ItemMarkerAppearance>
            <FillStyle MainColor="" SecondColor="">
            </FillStyle>
            <Border Color="" />
        </Appearance>
        <TextBlock>
            <Appearance Position-AlignedPosition="Center">
            </Appearance>
        </TextBlock>
    </Legend>
    <Series>
        <telerik:ChartSeries Name="Targeted Response Time">
            <Appearance>
                <FillStyle FillType="Solid" MainColor="Yellow">
                </FillStyle>
                <TextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Brown">
                </TextAppearance>
            </Appearance>
        </telerik:ChartSeries>
        <telerik:ChartSeries Name="Avg Response Time">
            <Appearance>
                <FillStyle FillType="Solid" MainColor="CadetBlue">
                </FillStyle>
                <TextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Brown">
                </TextAppearance>
            </Appearance>
        </telerik:ChartSeries>
        <telerik:ChartSeries Name="Targeted Resolution Time">
            <Appearance>
                <FillStyle FillType="Solid" MainColor="LightGreen">
                </FillStyle>
                <TextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Brown">
                </TextAppearance>
            </Appearance>
        </telerik:ChartSeries>
        <telerik:ChartSeries Name="Avg Resolution Time" >
            <Appearance>
                <FillStyle FillType="Solid" MainColor="DarkOrange">
                </FillStyle>
                <TextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Brown">
                </TextAppearance>
            </Appearance>
        </telerik:ChartSeries>
    </Series>
</telerik:RadChart>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states - your TargetedResponseTime property is not numeric and the YAxis is designed to show numeric values only. If you want to have custom Axis Labels (i.e. strings) - follow the Telerik's documentation [topic](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radchart-how-to-add-axis-labels-programmatically.html). The approach described is absolutely valid for both axes.

Kind Regards, Evgenia

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new Telerik's ASP.NET Chart, called RadHtmlChart which lets you configure DateTime axis for both - X and Y axes when series are numerical - Scatter and ScatterLine. If series, however, are categorical - Area, Line, Column, Bar, etc. DateTime axis can be used only for the X axis.

More information on the matter is available in [HtmlChart - Date Axis online demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/functionality/dateaxis/defaultcs.aspx) as well as in [Date Axis](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-date-axis.html) help article